# Pyspark how to append row to BigQuery table

Tags: pyspark, google-bigquery

I've a Pyspark program where at the end I need to append rows to a Bigquery table. I was able to create the table and load rows into it the first time but don't know how to keep on appending more rows.

This is my code snippet for loading into BQ the first time -

```
mydf.write.format('bigquery') \
        .option('table', 'my-project.my-dataset.my-table') \
        .option("temporaryGcsBucket","my-bucket") \
        .save()
```

Can anyone please help me here?

The complete exception, I get when "appending" rows -

> Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing
>   rows.
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:257)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:170)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:169)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
>           at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
>           at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
>           at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>           ... 1 more Caused by: net.razorvine.pickle.PickleException: expected zero arguments for construction of ClassDict (for
>   rdkit.Chem.rdchem.Mol)
>           at net.razorvine.pickle.objects.ClassDictConstructor.construct(ClassDictConstructor.java:23)
>           at net.razorvine.pickle.Unpickler.load_reduce(Unpickler.java:707)
>           at net.razorvine.pickle.Unpickler.dispatch(Unpickler.java:175)
>           at net.razorvine.pickle.Unpickler.load(Unpickler.java:99)
>           at net.razorvine.pickle.Unpickler.loads(Unpickler.java:112)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BatchEvalPythonExec$$anonfun$evaluate$1.apply(BatchEvalPythonExec.scala:90)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BatchEvalPythonExec$$anonfun$evaluate$1.apply(BatchEvalPythonExec.scala:89)
>           at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:435)
>           at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:441)
>           at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
>           at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.processNext(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:636)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:244)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:242)
>           at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1394)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:248)

Answer (score 4):

Simply set save mode to `append` :

```
df.write \
  .format('bigquery') \
  .option('table', 'my-project.my-dataset.my-table') \
  .option("temporaryGcsBucket","my-bucket") \
  .mode("append") \
  .save()
```

If you look at [spark-bigquery-connector](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector/blob/85a0ca2a6f67850ac39426eea679864ab3edf1a3/connector/src/main/scala/com/google/cloud/spark/bigquery/BigQueryWriteHelper.scala#L55) source code, the connector supports only save modes `overwrite` and `append`.

Comment: Hi @blackbishop, I'm getting error - `py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o75.save.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to write to BigQuery
        at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryWriteHelper.writeDataFrameToBigQuery(BigQueryWriteHelper.scala:62)` - while trying to "append" rows. Can you help?

Comment: Hi @dips_ag, is this the compelete errror message you get? Can you add the complete exception to the question?

Comment: Hi @blackbishop, I've added the exception message to my original question. Can you help me figure out what is that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The error looks very generic, maybe with more context about your  BigQuery Schema we could figure out what is wrong.